# Lambda Policy Permissions: How to set Function Policy for lambda functions from AWS console?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I can add permissions using lambda add permission API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_AddPermission.html

I clicked on designer button in the lambda function from AWS console, but it just displays the Function Policy content set from the API, and it's not editable.

My requirement is to add the lambda permissions through the AWS console. Couldn't find any references. 
Any help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
 - Go to Lambda console.
 - Check the role name that is attached to your lambda.
 - Go to IAM and click on roles on the left of the screen.
 - Search the role name that you figured out in step-2.
 - Add permission there.
```

Hopefully, it would help
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but when i add the IAM role and attach permissions to it, it displays the permissions under the execution role policy and did not apply the permissions when i executed the lambda function. It displays empty under function policy.
I m not sure about the difference between "Function policy" and "Execution Role" which displays under designer tab.

Comment: Thanks that works great. After attaching my custom Policy to the role attached to my Lambda, I can now see the updated list of services under "Resources that the function's role has access to appear here" in my Lambda designer section.